# Find the position of an element in matrix

Tags: javascript, algorithm, matrix

You have a matrix N*N. You move from trough the matrix by spiral. Now that you know how many steps you have taken, you want to know your position in the matrix.

Input/Output
[input] integer size

The size of the room.

[input] integer steps

The number of steps you have taken(1-based).

[output] an integer array

Array of length two, describing your position in the room(0-based).

Example

```
For size = 5 and steps = 20, the output should be [2, 3].
```

Your path can be shown as the following figure:

```
[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5], 
[16, 17, 18, 19,  6], 
[15,  x,  x, 20,  7], 
[14,  x,  x,  x,  8], 
[13, 12, 11, 10,  9]
```

The 20th step brought you to the second line and third column (0-based), so the answer is [2, 3].

I build a solution that can build such matrix for me

```
const initMatrix = size => {
  const matrix = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new Array(size);
  }
  return matrix;
};

const blindfolded = (size, steps) => {
  const matrix = initMatrix(size);
  let nc = size;
  let num = 1;
  for (let z = 0; z < nc; z++) {
    for (let i = z; i < nc; i++) {
      matrix[z][i] = num;
      num++;
    }
    for (let i = z + 1; i < nc; i++) {
      matrix[i][nc - 1] = num;
      num++;
    }
    for (let i = nc - 2; i >= z; i--) {
      matrix[nc - 1][i] = num;
      num++;
    }
    for (let i = nc - 2; i >= z + 1; i--) {
      matrix[i][z] = num;
      num++;
    }
   nc--;
 }

 for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
   for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
     console.log(matrix[i][j]);
   }
 }
};
blindfolded(7, 1);
```

But probably there should be another more optimal algorithm

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in constant time. The spiral looks like this:

[image]

To find number of coils for a given `steps`, one need to

```
ceil(sqrt(steps)/2 - 0.5) - 1                                                (1)
```

Side length on `i`-th level is `2*i+1`, we start count from zero.

Suppose `steps = 64` and center is `(5,5)`. Applying (1) one can find that number of full levels is three, so we are at `(8,8+1) = (8,9)` (bold black dot), and we did `49` steps for it. Then, side length on 4-th level is `2*4+1=9`, so subtract `7` vertically, subtract `8`, and we don't have any more steps to use, so finally we are at `(1,1)`.

Somehow this is not surprising, because we went through square `8x8`.

```js
function calc() {
var steps = window.steps.value;
if (steps <= 0) return "must be positive";
var ci = 5, cj = 5;
if (steps == 1) return ci + ", " + cj;
var level = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(steps)/2 - 0.5) - 1;
var ri = ci + level;
var rj = cj + level + 1;
var sideFull = 2 * level + 1;
steps -= sideFull * sideFull;
var side = sideFull + 2;
{
 var verUp = Math.min(steps, side - 2);
 steps -= verUp;
 ri -= verUp;
}
{
 var horLeft = Math.min(steps, side - 1);
 steps -= horLeft;
 rj -= horLeft;
}
{
 var verDown = Math.min(steps, side - 1);
 steps += verDown;
 ri -= verDown;
}
{
 var horRight = Math.min(steps, side - 1);
 rj + horRight;
}
return ri + ", " + rj;
}
```

```html
Center at (5,5), and steps = <input id="steps" />. <button onclick="answer.value = calc();" >Calc</button><br>
Answer: <input id="answer" disabled="disabled" />
```